# c++ explicit call to constructor and temporary object

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
    Test()  { cout << "Constructor is executed\n"; }
    ~Test() { cout << "Destructor is executed\n";  }
};

int main()
{
     Test();  // Explicit call to constructor

    return 0;
}
```

in above code we are calling constructor explicitly and When the constructor is called explicitly the compiler creates a nameless temporary object and it is immediately destroyed.
why do we need this temporary object??

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "need"ing the temporary object?

Comment: We need its side effect or we need it to call some function or to be params of some function

Comment: If the constructor and destructor are empty, then [there is no code generated](https://godbolt.org/g/ioUoov) with optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Because the constructor & destructor have side effects. They both print stuff.

If they had no side effects, then the compiler might be smart enough to figure out that it doesn't actually need to create the temporary, and skip it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The *functional type conversion notation* you are using, `Test(...)`, actually means "create a temporary object of type `Test`" from C++98 up to C++14. Therefore, the temporary is created, as requested, and the constructor is called in order to initialize the object. It does *not* mean "call the constructor". In fact, the execution of a constructor can never be separated from the creation of an object.

In C++17, `Test()` is a prvalue that is materialized since it is used as a discarded-value expression. At the point of materialization, the temporary object is created, and the constructor is called. It remains true that the execution of a constructor never occurs separately from the creation of an object.

Comment: By "In C++17, Test() is a prvalue that is materialized since it is used as a discarded-value expression." are you trying to convey something about mandatory copy elision?  I don't think I follow :(

Comment: @Curious Yes, maybe I wasn't clear enough, but with guaranteed copy elision, a prvalue expression no longer denotes an object in itself, but rather a potential object. Perhaps this distinction is too subtle in this context...

Comment: Can you, please, clarify what you mean by "constructor can never be separated from the **creation** of an object"?  What do you mean by "creation"?  Initialization?  Placement `new` expression can separate initialization from allocation.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich If the object has a nontrivial constructor, its lifetime does not begin until after the constructor has completed. Placement new creates the object; before the placement new call, all you have is some memory that the object will occupy, not the object itself.

Comment: **−1** All the rest of your answer is OK, but  “[the notation] does not mean "call the constructor"” is bull. That's exactly what it means, in this context. There is no contradiction with  "create a temporary object": it does that also, as you mention in the OK part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The standard (C++14) briefly mentions some circumstances of temporary object :

```
1. Binding a reference to a prvalue
2. Returning a prvalue 
3. A conversion that creates a prvalue
4. Throwing an exception
5. In some initializations
```

You can get the description of `prvalue` from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues). 
I have collected the circumstances from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-which-circumstances-C++-compiler-creates-temporary-objects/answer/Brian-Bi).

Answer (score 0):

Re

> **”** why do we need this temporary object??

… we don't. The compiler is free to optimize away, as long as the effect is *as if* the constructor and destructor, with side effects, had been called.

The compiler can't remove the constructor and destructor side effects because the standard explicitly requires it to not remove local objects whose construction or destruction has side effects:

**C++11 §3.7.3/3**<sub><sup>basic.std.auto/3</sup></sub>:

> **”**
>   If a variable with automatic storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, it shall not
>   be destroyed before the end of its block, nor shall it be eliminated as an optimization even if it appears to
>   be unused, except that a class object or its copy/move may be eliminated as specified in 12.8.